# Tensor notation, violation of Einstein summation convention allowed?

Tags: inverse, tensors

I have carefully constructed this identity
$$
M^u_{vk}b^kG^v_r=\delta^u_r
$$

where $b^h$ is just a vector and $G^v_r=G^v_r(b^h)$. Now I wish to investigate under what circumstances this implies the following identity
$$
M^u_{vk}G^v_mb^m=\delta^u_k
$$
At first I thought I could just substitute $b^m=\delta^m_kb^k$ in the **second** expression. This gives (using the first identity)
$$
M^u_{vk}b^k\delta^m_kG^v_m=\delta^u_m\delta^m_k=\delta^u_k
$$
But sadly I think there are too many k:s in the expression now (in violation of the index notation). And the rule is the index you rename needs to be "live", right?

I might even need to add some condition(s) on $M$ and $G$ for the first identity $\iff$ the second? Any thoughts or help appreciated!

Edit: changed to second expression, thanks to David Sheard.

Comment: What does $G^v_r=G^v_r(b^h)$ mean?

Comment: I think you've performed your substitution incorrectly. If you substitute $b^k=b^m\delta^k_m$  into the top expression you just get $M^u_{vk}b^m\delta^k_mG^v_r$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant substitute into the second expression,

Comment: $G^v_r=G^v_r(b^h)$ just means that $G$ is a function of-, or depends upon, $b^h$.

Comment: Write $B^u_{kr} = M^u_{vk} G^v_r$. Then the two are $ A^u_{kr} b^k = \delta^u_r$ and $ A^u_{rk} b^k = \delta^u_r$. Let say if $u$ is fixed, then you are asking if $A^u_{rk} b^k = A^u_{rk} b^r$ and this is not true.

Comment: Well, it is obviously true if $A^u_{rk}=A^u_{kr}$ ie if $A$ is symmetric in $rk$! That was kinda cool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arctic Char pointed out in the comments the second expression is easily implied if we impose the additional condition that the tensor $M^u_{vk}G^v_m$ is $symmetric$ in the pair of subscripts $k$ and $m$. Like so

$$
M^u_{vk}G^v_mb^m=M^u_{vm}G^v_kb^m=\delta^u_k
$$

Now I just have to figure out why the contracted product of the two tensors $M$ and $G$ exhibits this property. Obviously there is some kind of inverse relation between them and I need to study how they are constructed. That might be the subject of my next thread :)